# Loading a texture using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to load a texture via OpenGL for a 2d platformer and the code seems to be crashing on this exact part, but the lack of knowledge in C++ or openGL seems to be my problem, pls help!

```
bool Texture::LoadTextureFromFile( std::string path )
{
    //Texture loading success
    bool textureLoaded = false;

    //Generate and set current image ID
    GLuint imgID = 0;
    glGenTextures( 1, &imgID );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D ,imgID );

    //Load image
    GLboolean success = glLoadTextures( path.c_str() );

    //Image loaded successfully
    if( success == GL_TRUE )
    {
        //Convert image to RGBA
        // success = ilConvertImage( IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE );
        if( success == GL_TRUE )
        {
            //Create texture from file pixels
            textureLoaded = LoadTextureFromPixels32
            ( (GLuint*)glGetDoublev, (GLuint*)glGetIntegerv( GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH ), GLuint*(glGetIntegerv( GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT )) );
        }

        //Delete file from memory
        glDeleteTextures( 1, &imgID );
    }

    //Report error
    if( !textureLoaded )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load %s\n", path.c_str() );
    }

    return textureLoaded;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? What error do you get? Also, what did you do to pinpoint the location of the error? Did you step through your program with a debugger? If not, I'd highly suggest you do so!

Comment: Sorry,by crashing I meant the fact that the program didn't even want to compile. and the first problem was with `GLboolean success = glLoadTextures( path.c_str() );` and second was with `(GLuint*)glGetDoublev, (GLuint*)glGetIntegerv( GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH ), GLuint*(glGetIntegerv( GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT ))`

Comment: Then what does you compiler tell you?

Comment: with the first one it says identifier not found, but I think it needs the initialisation from opengl libraries. with the second one it says that the function doesn't accept 1 argument

Comment: Please update the question with the verbatim error. Also, what is `LoadTextureFromPixels32` is it a library function? If yes, from what library? If no, please show it's source.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible issues.

Firstly, where do you get glLoadTextures() from? And what does it do? That's not part of the OpenGL specification. It's not clear to me what it does. It's possible that this function does the entire texture loading for you, and the code below just screws things up.

Next, your first parameter to LoadTextureFromPixels32() is glGetDoubleV. You're passing it a pointer to the function glGetDoubleV, which is definitely NOT right. I assume that parameter expects a pointer to the loaded image data.

Finally, your code deletes the texture you just created with glDeleteTextures(). That makes no sense. Your texture object's ID is stored in imgID, which is a local variable. You're deleting it so the texture's gone.

The normal procedure for creating a texture is:

- Load the texture data (using something like SDL_image, or another image loading library)
- Create the texture object using glGenTextures(); NOTE: This is your handle to the texture; you MUST store this for future use
- Bind it glBindTexture()
- Load in the image data glTexture2D()

That's it.